# Mathspec and Dollar Symbols in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, xetex, mathspec

I'm using `mathspec` with `XeLaTeX` to typeset documents in a system font (Fira Sans but I don't think it matters). When I include punctuation and certain other symbols in math mode, they come out in Computer Modern.

I gather from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38711/punctuation-marks-in-math-mode-in-xetex-mathspec) that this is a known issue with `mathspec`, and I can use the code there to fix the issue for periods, commas, and the like.

But the fix doesn't seem to work for dollar signs. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Fira Sans Light}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{&}{\mathord}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`&}
\DeclareMathSymbol{$}{\mathpunct}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ampersands look good in text mode \& also in math mode: $A \,\&\, B$.\\
But dollar signs should look like thi\$, not thi$\$$.
\end{document}
```

My output looks like this: [image]

## Heading

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps [this related post regarding `\%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151529/164314) can help. It is also worth mentioning that [Fira Math](https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath) is now [on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/firamath), so an alternative would be `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{Fira Math}`.

Comment: But Fira Math might look a bit heavy with Fira Light....

Comment: Might try the workaround of `\mathrm{\$}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with "Fira Sans" rather than "Fira Sans Light" then the new ["Fira Math"](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/firamath) font mentioned in the OP comments, can make things much simpler, as you don't need to use `mathspec` at all.

On my Mac, after I have installed a selection of Fira fonts from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/Fira/tree/master/otf) and installed "Fira Math" from the link above, so that my FontBook shows these:

[image]

then I can typeset with Fira Sans as body and maths font with plain `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\begin{document}

\section{Heading}

Ampersands look good in text mode \& also in math mode: $A \mathbin{\&} B$.

\bigskip
\noindent
Dollar signs should look like thi\$ in text, and this in math $A \mathbin{\$} B$.

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: You don’t need to download and install Fira Sans from GitHub, since CTAN already has [`fira`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fira). My suggestion of `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}` will automatically detect the compile engine and use OpenType under XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.